# move mathced pattern to beginning of the line in file

Tags: shell-script, shell

Input:

```
    1991/10/15,DFD.T/SDFDS.Z/9887/15MAR/DFC/I.X/918875797553.G/IUYT/1/453.H/LPJB
1991/10/15,DFD.T/RUDFR.Z/9887/15MAR/DFC/I.X/918875797554.G/IUYT/1/453.H/LPJB
```

Expected:

```
.X/918875797553.T/SDFDS,1991/10/15,DFD.Z/9887/15MAR/DFC/I.G/IUYT/1/453.H/LPJB
.X/918875797554.T/RUDFR,1991/10/15,DFD.Z/9887/15MAR/DFC/I.G/IUYT/1/453.H/LPJB
```

Need to move .X/followed value and.T/followed value to the beginning of the line.
someone please suggest solution for the above.
I have thousands of lines in a file and want to convert them in the same format.

Comment: Is the pattern always in the same format `.X/number of numbers.T`?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, I have edited the question. Sorry for not making clear question. yes the pattern is same.

Comment: You are moving the beginning of the line too, would you explain exactly what has to be moved where?

Comment: first line has .T/SDFDS and .X/918875797553 and needs to move them to start of the line as .X/918875797553.T/SDFDS,1991/10/15 and similar way for remaining lines. I am not moving line.

Comment: I don't the reason why it was voted as negative, the question is absolutely valid and ""@Freddy"" has already answered the question, which is working as rocket.

Comment: The reason is that in this site is expected some code tried by OP, and work from that. (I didn't downvote BTW).

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, Actually I have tried but which was not working as expeceted and not in optimistic way, so I didn't paste here.

Comment: You should post what you tried next time to avoid downvotes.

Comment: sure and thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed` and two substitutions:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\(\.T\/[^.]*\)/\2,\1/;s/\(.*\)\(\.X\/[^.]*\)/\2\1/' file
```

This moves `.T/` followed by any non-`.` characters to the beginning of the line and adds a `,` in the first substitution.
It then moves `.X/` followed by any non-`.` characters to the beginning of the line in the second substitution.

Comment: @Freddy, If my input has repeated .X values and need to move all of them, how can I achieve it. 1991/10/15,DFD.T/RUDFR.Z/9887/15MAR/DFC/I.X/918875797554.X/918875797550.X/918875797558.G/IUYT/1/453.H/LPJB. 
I need output like .X/918875797554.X/918875797550.X/918875797558.T/RUDFR,1991/10/15,DFD.Z/9887/15MAR/DFC/I.G/IUYT/1/453.H/LPJB. note that always .X values will not be followed by .Z

Comment: If you know the number of repetitions beforehand (here `{3}`), you can use `sed -E 's/(.*)(\.T\/[^.]*)/\2,\1/;s/(.*)((\.X\/[^.]*){3})/\2\1/' file`.
If you need a dynamic solution, please post a new question.

Comment: ok.. sure will post new question.