# move pattern(which may be dynamic repetitions) to the beginning of the line

Tags: shell-script, shell

I was able to get output if pattern occurs only once in line. using the following command.

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\(\.T\/[^.]*\)/\2,\1/;s/\(.*\)\(\.X\/[^.]*\)/\2\1/' file
```

Input:

```
1991/10/15,DFD.T/SDFDS.Z/9887/15MAR/DFC/I.X/918875797553.G/IUYT/1/453.H/LPJB
1991/10/15,DFD.T/RUDFR.Z/9887/15MAR/DFC/I.X/918875797554.G/IUYT/1/453.H/LPJB
```

Expected Ouptut:

```
.X/918875797553.T/SDFDS,1991/10/15,DFD.Z/9887/15MAR/DFC/I.G/IUYT/1/453.H/LPJB
.X/918875797554.T/RUDFR,1991/10/15,DFD.Z/9887/15MAR/DFC/I.G/IUYT/1/453.H/LPJB
```

But in case if I have dynamic reptitions of mathced pattern,please suggest optimistic solution.

```
1991/10/15,SUN.T/IUDFW.Z/0136/15MAR/KWW/I.X/918875797554.X/918875797550.X/918875797558.G/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK. 
1991/10/15,SUN.T/IUDFW.Q/0136/15SEP/KWW/I.X/918875797557.X/918875797550.X/918875797558.X/918875797559.W/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK.
1991/10/15,SUN.T/BJYE.Z/0136/03MAR/KWW/I.X/918875797551.L/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK.
```

I need output like as follows.

```
.X/918875797554.X/918875797550.X/9188757975581.T/IUDFW,991/10/15,SUN.Z/0136/15MAR/KWW/I.G/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK. 
.X/918875797557.X/918875797550.X/918875797558.X/918875797559.T/IUDFW,1991/10/15,SUN.Q/0136/15SEP/KWW/I.W/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK.
.X/918875797551.T/BJYE,1991/10/15,SUN.Z/0136/03MAR/KWW/I.L/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK.
```

Comment: @αғsнιη, for yesterday's question, the answer is working absolutely fine for single occurance of .X/918875797551 but if have dynamic repetitions like I explained above it's not working. **first line has 3 values for .X and second line has 4 values and thrid line has only one value.**

Comment: Is the first `.X/` always prefixed by `/I`?

Comment: No. It will always change.

Comment: @αғsнιη, I got the original input file yesterday, So I couldn't post in the initial question.

Comment: OK, I'm sorry, you have asked [because someone requested you to open a new question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/633000/move-mathced-pattern-to-beginning-of-the-line-in-file#comment1185171_633006). btw, I'm not downvoter

Comment: ok. No problem. Thanks.

Comment: In the first line of the output, it says `/IUDFW,991` instead of `/IUDFW,1991`, I guess is a typo?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For such questions it is advisable to invoke GNU sed in extensive regex mode (-E) so that excessive backslashes and \{1,\} don't get in the way of regex readability. Also, we can do it in multiple calls to s/// command after fencing the desired chunk to be moved around one at a time.

```
sed -Ee '
  s|\.T/[^.]+|\n&\n|
  s|(.*)\n(.*)\n|\2,\1|
  s|(\.X/[^.]+)+|\n&\n|
  s|(.*)\n(.*)\n|\2\1|
' file
```

**P.S.:**
Assuming leading whitespace in are a typo. Also, your first line in the multi pattern scenario your output doesn't match your input.

Comment: I borrowed your PS.

Comment: My heartful thanks to your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is working, given the example:

```bsh
$ sed 's:\([^.]*\)\.\([^.]*\)\.\([^.]*[A-Z]\)\([.X0-9/]*\)\(.*\)$:\4\2,\1.\3.\5:'
```

Lets compare:

```
# OP's
.X/918875797554.X/918875797550.X/9188757975581.T/IUDFW,991/10/15,SUN.Z/0136/15MAR/KWW/I.G/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK. 
.X/918875797557.X/918875797550.X/918875797558.X/918875797559.T/IUDFW,1991/10/15,SUN.Q/0136/15SEP/KWW/I.W/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK.
.X/918875797551.T/BJYE,1991/10/15,SUN.Z/0136/03MAR/KWW/I.L/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK.

# command output
.X/918875797554.X/918875797550.X/918875797558.T/IUDFW,1991/10/15,SUN.Z/0136/15MAR/KWW/I.G/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK. 
.X/918875797557.X/918875797550.X/918875797558.X/918875797559.T/IUDFW,1991/10/15,SUN.Q/0136/15SEP/KWW/I.W/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK.
.X/918875797551.T/BJYE,1991/10/15,SUN.Z/0136/03MAR/KWW/I.L/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK.
```

---

**P.S.:** Assuming leading whitespace in are a typo. Also, your first line in the multi pattern scenario your output doesn't match your input.

Comment: As I mentioned , input is 1991/10/15,DFD.T/RUDFR.Z/9887/15MAR/DFC/I.X/918875797554.X/918875797550.X/918875797558.G/IUYT/1/453.H/LPJB. 
and expected output is .X/918875797554.X/918875797550.X/918875797558.T/RUDFR,1991/10/15,DFD.Z/9887/15MAR/DFC/I.
G/IUYT/1/453.H/LPJB.  
But above solution is not working.

Comment: input line stats with date, output line starts with .X/918875797554.X/918875797550.X/918875797558 and followed by .T/RUDFR, and date. I couldn't understand statement identical ?

Comment: your command only working for given example, and If have input like 1991/10/15,SUN.T/IUDFW.Z/0136/15MAR/KWW/I.X/918875797554.X/918875797550.X/918875797558.X/918875797559.G/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK. command is not able to required output format. My input file contains .X values not fixed positiions, some lilnes contains one and some contains  five repetitions, some lines contains seven repetitions.

Comment: and note that .X will not have always .G in next position and same for .T also, .T value also not have .Z in next position.

Comment: 1991/10/15,SUN.T/IUDFW.Z/0136/15MAR/KWW/I.X/918875797554.X/918875797550.X/918875797558.G/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK. 
1991/10/15,SUN.T/IUDFW.Q/0136/15SEP/KWW/I.X/918875797557.X/918875797550.X/918875797558.X/918875797559.W/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK.
1991/10/15,SUN.T/BJYE.Z/0136/03MAR/KWW/I.X/918875797551.L/PLMW/1/SPI.H/XZTK.  Thanks a lot in advance for spending your valuable time.

Comment: I have edited question as per your suggestion, please ignore space of beginning of first line.